# How to ensure that the following logic for jstree custom context menu works correctly?

Tags: copy, contextmenu, jstree, paste, cut

I would like this to work like explorer.exe in Windows, that is only if we have cut or copied an element that the paste item will appear.. this works sometimes but perhaps there is something that I'm missing.. if there is a way to improve it to work always I would be happy to know your thoughts on it.

```
           jQuery.noConflict();

        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        // This is for the context menu to bind with operations on the right clicked node
                function customMenu(node) {
            // The default set of all items

        var control;

            var items = {

                      createItem: { 
                    label: "Create",
                    action: function (node) {   return {createItem: this.create(node) }; }
                },

                        renameItem: { 
                    label: "Rename",
                    action: function (node) {  return {renameItem: this.rename(node) }; }
                },

                    deleteItem: { 
                    label: "Delete",
                    action: function (node) {     return {deleteItem: this.remove(node) }; },
                    "separator_after": true

                },
                        copyItem: { 
                                label: "Copy",
                                action: function (node) {  $(node).addClass("copy");  return {copyItem: this.copy(node)  }; }
                },
                                cutItem: { 
                                label: "Cut",
                                action: function (node) { $(node).addClass("cut");  return {cutItem: this.cut(node)  }; }
                },
                        pasteItem: { 
                                label: "Paste",
                                action: function (node) {  $(node).addClass("paste");    return {pasteItem: this.paste(node) }; }
                }


            };


            // We go over all the selected items as the context menu only takes action on the one that is right clicked
                $.jstree._reference("#{$id_arr[$k]}").get_selected(false, true).each(function(index,element){   

                        if ( $(element).attr("id") != $(node).attr("id") )
                        {
                            // Let's deselect all nodes that are unrelated to the context menu -- selected but are not the one right clicked

                            $("#{$id_arr[$k]}").jstree("deselect_node", '#'+$(element).attr("id") );  
                        }
                    });



            // Let's loop through all elements and try to find if the paste operation was done already      
            $("#{$id_arr[$k]}").find("li").each(function(index,element){        

             if($(node).hasClass("paste") )
             { 
                //We are asumming that the current event is pasted so remove the Paste from the context menu
                 control =0; 
                // and from any node that has the class for cut or copy.. there is no other way as dnd, move and copy, cut are a move operation for jstree
                    if( $(element).hasClass("copy") ) $(element).removeClass("copy");   
                    if ( $(element).hasClass("cut") ) $(element).removeClass("cut");
             }  
           if( ($(element).hasClass("copy") || $(element).hasClass("cut") )  )
           { 
            control =1;
           }

           //we already pasted the node
           if( $(element).hasClass("paste") )
           { 
           $(this).removeClass("paste");
             }

            });


               switch (control)
               {
                case 1:
                                    switch ($(node).attr("rel"))
                                                {

                                                        case "drive":
                                                            delete items.renameItem;
                                                            delete items.deleteItem;
                                                            delete items.cutItem;
                                                            delete items.copyItem;
                                                        break;

                                                }
                    break;


                case 0:
                                                switch ($(node).attr("rel"))
                                                        {

                                                                case "drive":
                                                                    delete items.renameItem;
                                                                    delete items.deleteItem;
                                                                    delete items.cutItem;
                                                                    delete items.copyItem;
                                                                delete items.pasteItem;
                                                                break;

                                                                case "default":
                                                              delete items.pasteItem;
                                                                break;

                                                        }   
                break;

                default:                switch ($(node).attr("rel"))
                                                        {

                                                                case "drive":
                                                                    delete items.renameItem;
                                                                    delete items.deleteItem;
                                                                    delete items.cutItem;
                                                                    delete items.copyItem;
                                                                delete items.pasteItem;
                                                                break;

                                                                case "default":
                                                              delete items.pasteItem;
                                                                break;

                                                        }   

                break;

                    }



            return items;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this does it, but can it work for all cases? If the cut or paste is the current node then I don't want to show the option on it for paste, but on the other nodes only.. Hope that anyone can take a look or that it may help out someone trying to achieve the same functionality without looking into bindings:

```
                <div id="$id_arr[$k]" class="jstree_container"></div>
        </div>
        </li>

        <!-- JavaScript neccessary for this tree : {$value} -->
        <script type="text/javascript" >
           jQuery.noConflict();

        jQuery(function ($) {

        // This is for the context menu to bind with operations on the right clicked node
                function customMenu(node) {
            // The default set of all items

        var control;

            var items = {

                      createItem: { 
                    label: "Create",
                    action: function (node) {   return {createItem: this.create(node) }; }
                },

                        renameItem: { 
                    label: "Rename",
                    action: function (node) {  return {renameItem: this.rename(node) }; }
                },

                    deleteItem: { 
                    label: "Delete",
                    action: function (node) {     return {deleteItem: this.remove(node) }; },
                    "separator_after": true

                },
                        copyItem: { 
                                label: "Copy",
                                action: function (node) {  $(node).addClass("copy");  return {copyItem: this.copy(node)  }; }
                },
                                cutItem: { 
                                label: "Cut",
                                action: function (node) { $(node).addClass("cut");  return {cutItem: this.cut(node)  }; }
                },
                        pasteItem: { 
                                label: "Paste",
                                action: function (node) {  $(node).addClass("paste");    return {pasteItem: this.paste(node) }; }
                }


            };


            // We go over all the selected items as the context menu only takes action on the one that is right clicked
                $.jstree._reference("#{$id_arr[$k]}").get_selected(false, true).each(function(index,element)
                {   

                        if ( $(element).attr("id") != $(node).attr("id") )
                        {
                            // Let's deselect all nodes that are unrelated to the context menu -- selected but are not the one right clicked

                            $("#{$id_arr[$k]}").jstree("deselect_node", '#'+$(element).attr("id") );  
                        }
                    });




        //if any previous click has the class for copy or cut
             $("#{$id_arr[$k]}").find("li").each(function(index,element)        
             {  
                        if ($(element) != $(node) )
                    {   
                        if(  $(element).hasClass("copy") || $(element).hasClass("cut") ) control=1;
                    }
                    else if(  $(node).hasClass("cut") || $(node).hasClass("copy"))
                        {
                        control=0;
                        }
            });


            //only remove the class for cut or copy if the current operation is to paste
        if($(node).hasClass("paste") )
        {   
            control=0;   
            // Let's loop through all elements and try to find if the paste operation was done already      
            $("#{$id_arr[$k]}").find("li").each(function(index,element)
            {       
                if( $(element).hasClass("copy") ) $(this).removeClass("copy");  
                    if ( $(element).hasClass("cut") ) $(this).removeClass("cut"); 
                  if ( $(element).hasClass("paste") ) $(this).removeClass("paste");  
                });
        }


               switch (control)
               {
                //Remove the paste item from the context menu
                case 0:
                                switch ($(node).attr("rel"))
                                    {

                                            case "drive":
                                                delete items.renameItem;
                                                delete items.deleteItem;
                                                delete items.cutItem;
                                                delete items.copyItem;
                                            delete items.pasteItem;
                                            break;

                                            case "default":
                                          delete items.pasteItem;
                                            break;

                                    }   
                break;

               //Remove the paste item from the context menu only on the node that has either copy or cut added class
                        case 1:
                        if( $(node).hasClass("cut") || $(node).hasClass("copy") )
                        {
                                                switch ($(node).attr("rel"))
                                                {

                                                                case "drive":
                                                                    delete items.renameItem;
                                                                    delete items.deleteItem;
                                                                    delete items.cutItem;
                                                                    delete items.copyItem;
                                                                delete items.pasteItem;
                                                                break;

                                                                case "default":
                                                              delete items.pasteItem;
                                                                break;


                                                }
                                        }   
                                            else //Re-enable it on the clicked node that does not have the cut or copy class
                                                {
                                    switch ($(node).attr("rel"))
                                                {

                                                        case "drive":
                                                            delete items.renameItem;
                                                            delete items.deleteItem;
                                                            delete items.cutItem;
                                                            delete items.copyItem;
                                                        break;

                                                }       
                                            }   

                    break;

                //initial state don't show the paste option on any node
                default:                switch ($(node).attr("rel"))
                                                        {

                                                                case "drive":
                                                                    delete items.renameItem;
                                                                    delete items.deleteItem;
                                                                    delete items.cutItem;
                                                                    delete items.copyItem;
                                                                    delete items.pasteItem;
                                                                break;

                                                                case "default":
                                                              delete items.pasteItem;
                                                                break;

                                                        }   

                break;

                    }

            return items;

        }




        $("#{$id_arr[$k]}").jstree({


                // List of active plugins used
                "plugins" : [ "themes","json_data", "ui", "crrm" , "hotkeys" , "types" , "dnd", "contextmenu"],  

                "contextmenu" : { "items" : customMenu  , "select_node": true},
```